# A Conditional probability problem and binomial formula

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem

a buyer will accept a lot of 100 articles if a sample of 5 picked at random and inspected contains no defects. What is the probability that the buyer will accept the lot if it contains 10 defective articles?

I have tried binomial formula, decision trees and nothing works to arrive at the correct answer of .58. The closest result I got was (.095)/(.95)(.1)+(.9)(.05))=.68 , but it's still not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you don't put back the ones that have already been picked. Then, the probability of picking 5 good ones in a row is:
$$
\left(\frac{90}{100}\right)\left(\frac{89}{99}\right)\left(\frac{88}{98}\right)\left(\frac{87}{97}\right)\left(\frac{86}{96}\right)=0.583752.
$$

---

Alternatively, there are $\binom{90}{5}$ ways to pick 5 out of 90 good ones. Divide this by $\binom{100}{5}$, the number of ways to pick 5 out of 100, will also yield $0.583752$.

Comment: Thank you!so is this more like a geometric distribution?

Comment: @ArmadillaPetrovna This is more like a "binomial distribution" but using "sampling without replacement", instead of "with".

Comment: @GrahamKemp , now I understand it, thank you very much!